# Refer to some equation number in different environments

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, formatting

I hope there is a solution for this. When I refer to some equation I always get something like `37`, but I would like to have `(37)`. I could make a new command but the problem is I use many kind of environments in my text: equation (needs `\eqref`), multline (needs `\ref`), theorems (need `\ref`). I don't want parantheses when referring to theorem numbers. 
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of the equations causing these problems? You usage of `\label` could be incorrect.

Comment: Lockstep provided me a solution, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use the *"extension of counter referencing"* described in section 53.2 of [source2e](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf) and then redefine `\p@equation`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\refstepcounter[1]{%
  \stepcounter{#1}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel
  {\csname p@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
\renewcommand{\p@equation}[1]{(#1)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{foo}\label{foo}

\begin{equation}\label{test}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

See equation~\ref{test} in section~\ref{foo}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

if you're using `amsmath`, just use `\eqref{ <label> }` which includes the parentheses and keeps the whole thing upright even in an italic (e.g. theorem) environment.  it really doesn't matter what you're using it for; it should work with any label.

reading the question more carefully, you say you don't want parentheses when referring to thworems.  then just use `\ref` -- but if you'd like them upright like `\eqref`, then use `\textup{\ref{...}}` when not in a "guaranteed" upright environment'